# Return the largest number of consecutive "special symbols" in the string s

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm having trouble with this homework problem.

`SPECIAL_SYMBOLS = '!@#$%^&*()_+=[]?/'`

```
def symbol_count(s:str): -> int
    """Return the largest number of consecutive "special symbols" in the 
    string s.
    >>> symbol_count(’c0mput3r’)
    0
    >>> symbol_count(’H! [here’)
    1
    >>> symbol_count(’h3!!&o world@#’)
    3
    """
    lst = []
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(s)-1):
        if s[i] in SPECIAL_SYMBOLS:
            count +=1
            if s[i+1] not in SPECIAL_SYMBOLS:
                lst.append(count)
                count = 0
            else:
                count += 1
    if lst == []:
        return 0
    return max(lst)
```

however, for the last example i get 5 instead of 3 so im guessing my count is not reinitializing to 0. I was wondering why this was the case. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3):

You problem is here:

```
else:
    count += 1
```

It ends up double counting consecutive special characters.  Just remove both of those lines.

Comment: Thank you so much sir! Really saved me there.